# c++ find process handle without FindWindow function

Tags: c++, handle, findwindow

i tryied to find the process handle,

```
HWND handle = FindWindow(0 ,TEXT("window title"));
```

i need window title
Let's say that I have tow process with the same title

so i want to make something like:

```
for each p as process in process.getProcessByName("notepad")

if process.processname = "notepad" then

handle = p.handle

exit for

end if

next
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686832(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: i need something like getProcessByName

Comment: You can enumerate through using those functions and check the name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enumerate the running processes yourself looking for the names manually.  You can do that using either:

1) `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, `Process32First()`, and `Process32Next()`. See MSDN for an example:

[Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701.aspx)

2) `EnumProcesses()`, `OpenProcess()`, `EnumProcessModules()` and `GetModuleBaseName()`.  See MSDN for an example:

[Enumerating All Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623.aspx)

3) use WMI to enumerate the items in the `Win32_Process` collection.